# How to query azure SQL from node.js server

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm having some trouble with querying my DB on azure sql (I am very new to sql). I'm following the steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs, but it only includes tutorial steps on how to read tables, not manipulate them. I am trying to do INSERT and DELETE requests on my Node.js server, but I am getting a request error in one of the node modules, which makes me think that I'm going about requesting the operations wrong.

Here's some code:

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

// Create connection to database
var config =
{
    userName: 'user_name',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'server_name',
    options:
    {
        database: '_dbname'
        , encrypt: true
    }
}
var connection = new Connection(config);

// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on('connect', function (err) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
else {
    queryDatabase();
}
}

//this works fine, it's for initially loading the data from the database
function queryDatabase() {
console.log('\nReading rows from the Table...');
let obj = {};
let objs = [];
let request;
// Read all rows from table
request = new Request(
    "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TABLE_NAME]",
    function (err, rowCount, rows) {
        console.log('-- Done');
    }
);
//this is for when an admin adds content to the app, SQL table not changing, 
//node.js throws error
socket.on('add item', item => {
    let index = getCollectionIndexById(item.id);
    collections[index].items.push(item.item);
    io.sockets.emit('add item', item);

    request = new Request(`INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE_NAME](Id, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4)
     VALUES (`
        + item.id + ','
        + item.item.attr2 + ','
        + item.item.attr3 + ','
        + item.item.attr4 + ','
        + null, function (err, rowCount, rows) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('> requested db to insert item');
        });
    connection.execSql(request);
    console.log('> item sent to app');
});
//for when the admin removes content from the app, same error 
socket.on('rm item', item => {
    collections[getCollectionIndexById(item.id)].items.splice(item.index, 1);
    io.sockets.emit('rm item', { "id": item.id, index: item.index });

    request = new Request(`DELETE FROM [dbo].[TABLE_NAME] WHERE Id= `
        + item.id + ` AND attr1= ` + item.item.attr1, function (err, rowCount, rows) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('> requested db to remove item')
        });
    connection.execSql(request);

    console.log('> sent request to remove item');

});
```

The exact error msg is `RequestError: Incorrect syntax near 'esse'.`, and its in one of the node modules called `tedious` in `request.js`.

So in summary, if anyone knows of a way to query Azure SQL Db's to make inserts and deletes, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `)` in the 'insert' SQL. Also, you'd need to set string value with single quotes of course.

Change the following lines of code

```
request = new Request(`INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE_NAME](Id, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4)
     VALUES (`
        + item.id + ','
        + item.item.attr2 + ','
        + item.item.attr3 + ','
        + item.item.attr4 + ','
        + null, function (err, rowCount, rows) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('> requested db to insert item');
        });
    connection.execSql(request);
```

to

```
request = new Request(`INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE_NAME](Id, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4) VALUES ('${item.id}', '${item.item.attr2}', '${item.item.attr3}', '${item.item.attr4}' null)`, function (err, rowCount, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('> requested db to insert item');
});
connection.execSql(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find an example [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2015/05/11/getting-started-with-node-js-on-microsoft-sql-server-and-azure-sql-database/) of how to INSERT records on a table using NodeJs and queryRaw.

```
conn.queryRaw("INSERT SalesLT.Product (Name, ProductNumber, StandardCost, ListPrice, SellStartDate) OUTPUT INSERTED.ProductID VALUES ('SQL Server Express 102', 'SQLEXPRESS 102', 0, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)", function (err, results)
```

You can use queryRaw also to DELETE records on a table.

Hope this helps.